# How do I Sum Hour and Minutes SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column in my report that contains text values like:

```
             01:30
             00:45
             02:15
```

And so on. How do I get a total like this?

```
             04:30
```

As a total time spent. I am trying this Expression -

```
= FLOOR(Sum(Cint(Left(Fields!est_pack_time.Value,2)), "DataSet1") ) & ":" & RIGHT("0" & (Sum(Cint(Right(Fields!est_pack_time.Value,2)), "DataSet1") MOD 60), 2)
```

This gives me something close but it is still not right. I am summing the total time across the entire dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track - your expression is just not carrying the extra hours from summing up the minutes into the total hour time.

The updated expression will be something like this:

```
=Right("0" & Sum(CInt(Left(Fields!est_pack_time.Value,2)), "DataSet1")
    + Floor(Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!est_pack_time.Value,2)), "DataSet1") / 60),2)
  & ":" & Sum(CInt(Right(Fields!est_pack_time.Value,2)), "DataSet1") Mod 60
```

This is taking the total from the hours, adding the overflow from the total minutes, then concatenating the minutes to this string. It's also padding the hours with a leading zero to make sure the string is always 5 characters.

Works for me in a quick test:

[image]

[image]

Finally, it probably goes without saying that if at all possible it's best to move away from storing time durations in a text format, but of course that might not be possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
=split(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value)).TotalHours,".").GetValue(0)  &":"
& Format(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value)).TotalMinutes mod 60,"00")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=replace( left(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value)).TotalHours,3)&":"
& right(TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TotalHours.Value)).TotalHours,3)*60,".","")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and go through the [help]. You might also want to read [answer].